# Hakell does not macth types of variables

Tags: haskell

My question is about the function I am trying to implement. It soulf unjoin String into the list of Strings. Smth like this Hello World-> [Hello, World]

```
unjoin :: String -> [String]
unjoin [] = []
unjoin cs = unjoin' [] cs
    where
        unjoin' :: String -> String -> [String] 
        unjoin' acc [] = acc
        unjoin' acc (' ':cs) = acc : unjoin' [] cs
        unjoin' acc (  c:cs) = unjoin' (acc ++ [c]) cs
```

Error by compiling

```
u2.hs:50:34: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [String]
        Actual type: String

    • In the expression: acc
      In an equation for ‘unjoin'’: unjoin' acc [] = acc
      In an equation for ‘unjoin’:
          unjoin cs
            = unjoin' [] cs
            where
                unjoin' :: String -> String -> [String]
                unjoin' acc [] = acc
                unjoin' acc (' ' : cs) = acc : unjoin' [] cs
                unjoin' acc (c : cs) = unjoin' (acc ++ [c]) cs
   |
50 |                 unjoin' acc [] = acc    |                                  ^^^
```

I thought that String type = [char] type
Where am I  wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Haskell error messages sometimes look intimidating but in fact they mostly tell you everything. It first says what type it expected but actually what it got... then it talks about the guy who disappointed it and where it lives... So you are supposed to check the type signature of `unjoin` and focus on the suspect `acc` to solve the crime.

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the first equation of your helper function:

```
unjoin' :: String -> String -> [String] 
unjoin'    acc       []      = acc
```

When you take `acc` as argument, you take it as a `String` (or `[Char]`, if you prefer -- that's the same type.)

When you return `acc`, however, you claim that's a `[String]` (or `[[Char]]`). But that's a different type!

My guess is that you actually want

```
unjoin' :: [String] -> String -> [String] 
        -- ^^^^^^^^ --
```

but in such case you'll need to adapt the other equations. Maybe, try to follow this path:

```
unjoin' acc    []       = ...
unjoin' []     (' ':cs) = ...  -- found space, no previous word
unjoin' []     (  c:cs) = ...  -- found nonspace, no previous word
unjoin' (x:xs) (' ':cs) = ...  -- found space, previous word x
unjoin' (x:xs) (  c:cs) = ...  -- found nonspace, previous word x
```

You'll probably need to use `reverse` at some point: it's easier to produce lists in the opposite order and then reverse them at the very end.

Comment: 1. I cannot understand why is it needed to rewrite the first equation .
2. Even if I place first argument ([String]) into brakets  I get even more errors

Comment: @Fedo You don't see the difference between `String` and `[String]`?

Comment: No, could you please clarify

Comment: @chepner No, could you please clarify

Comment: `String` is `[Char]`. `[String]` is `[[Char]]`.